# printing intermediate multiplication using loop

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, rstudio, matrix-multiplication

I have data frame 'df' which has 8*8 rows and columns.

here i am getting the answer directly the 5th multiplication, i want all the intermediate multiplications answers.

And i also want the code in loop for 15 times, so there will be 15 intermediate multiplication outputs.

```
Code: 

p <- eigen(df)$vector
d <- eigen(df)$values

n <- 5
p %*% diag(d^n) %*% solve(p)
```

expected output will: if i am multiplying n = 15 times, then there should be 15 matrices for each intermediate multiplication.

please help.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean power (X^n) can do the following:

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
n <- 5

pows <- list()
pows[[1]] <- mat
for (i in 2:n) {
    pows[[i]] <- pows[[i - 1]] %*% pows[[1]]
}

p <- eigen(mat)$vector
d <- eigen(mat)$values
res <- p %*% diag(d^n) %*% solve(p)

all(res - pows[[n]] < 1e-6)
```

Can also use:

```
library(expm)
mat %^% n
```

Comment: i installed the expm library and i used mat %^% but now the problem is its only showing 5th matrix if give n = 5, i want all the intermediate output for matrix 1,2,3,4,5. can you help me editing this in for loop.

Comment: `for (i in 1:5) { mat %^% i}`.